# QGIS 2/3 min/max values

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a question regarding the two QGIS Versions 2 and 3. When I load exactly the same raster file into QGIS 2 and QGIS 3 I get different min/max values, how is this possible? I have used the same coordination system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have different rendering settings in your both QGIS 2 and 3. Please check the setting from `Settings -> Options -> Rendering Settings`, especially the Cumulative pixel count cut limits:

Here is my settings in QGIS 3 (the default):

[image]

and in QGIS 2 (But here I adjusted for my purpose):

[image]

So maybe the settings are different in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I changed the settings and now the values are the same.